# Sidebar with height 100vh doesn't fill page if other content on page causes scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I'm building a sidebar in React and I'm trying to set the height to fill the entire page even if other content on the page goes beyond the initial window size.

Right now it only goes to the bottom of the initial page height, and if content on the page-- next to the sidebar, not inside of it --overflows, the user can scroll and the content is visible, but the sidebar stops at the end of the initial page height.

[Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSwRp.jpg) of what I'm describing

I've tried the following:

```
min-height: 100vh;
height: 100vh;
---
min-height: 100vh;
height: 1px;
---
min-height: 100vh;
height: 100vh;
max-height: 500vh;
---
html, body {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
```

[Update] I've tried using all the different sizing I can think of and have seen online. % all the way from html to the container of the sidebar, vh all the way down, min-height all the way down, min-height & max-height all the way down, different browsers to see if it's chrome/firefox. I think the issue is a conceptual one with how sizing works in CSS but I don't know what questions to ask to find the answer.

To no avail. I've looked around for similar issues and haven't found any solutions that work for me.

I'm not a frontend guy so I'm not entirely sure why this isn't working.

Here is the stylesheet for the sidebar and its ancestors:

```
html {
  font-size: 10px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
  height: -webkit-fill-available;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-height: -webkit-fill-available;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', 'Roboto', 'Oxygen',
    'Ubuntu', 'Cantarell', 'Fira Sans', 'Droid Sans', 'Helvetica Neue',
    sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

#root {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-right: 5%;
  width: 90%;
  color: rgb(58,58,58);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.Settings {
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.Settings-Sidebar {
  display: flex;
  overflow: visible;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-height: -webkit-fill-available;
  width: 34%;
  background: rgb(58,58,58);
  color: white;
}
```

and the react component in case its relevant (wip):

```
const Settings = () => {
  const user = useSelector(state => state.authReducer.user);
  const loading = useSelector(state => state.loadingReducer.isLoading);
  const location = useLocation();
  const hash = location.hash;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [active, setActive] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!active) {
      const activeElement = document.querySelector('.Settings-Sidebar-Option.active');
      setActive(activeElement);
    }
    dispatch(stopLoading());
    if (hash.includes('#confirm-email')) {
      const target = document.querySelector('#settings-confirm-option');
      target.click();
    }
  }, [active, dispatch, hash]);

  if (user.username === undefined) return <Redirect to="/" />

  if (loading) {
    return <Loading />
  }

  const setActiveSetting = (evt) => {
    const target = evt.target
    // Prevent changing active element to random whitespace
    if (target.classList.contains('Settings-Sidebar-Option')) {
      // remove the active class from all setting options
      for (let sibling of target.parentElement.children) {
        sibling.classList.remove('active');
      }
      target.classList.add('active');
      setActive(target);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="Settings">
      <div className="Settings-Sidebar">
        <h1 className="Settings-Sidebar-Header">Settings</h1>
        <div className="Settings-Sidebar-Content" onClick={setActiveSetting}>
          <h2 className="Settings-Sidebar-Option active" id="settings-general-option">General</h2>
          {!user.confirmed ? (
            <h2 className="Settings-Sidebar-Option" id="settings-confirm-option">Verify Email</h2>
          ) : null}
          <h2 className="Settings-Sidebar-Option" id="settings-contact-option">Contact</h2>
          <h2 className="Settings-Sidebar-Option" id="settings-about-option">About</h2>
          <h2 className="Settings-Sidebar-Option" id="settings-delete-option">Delete Account</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="Settings-Content">
        {active ? <SettingsContent current={active.innerText} /> : null}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: You need to use `position` property of `CSS` to your sidebar container to get the desired result.

Comment: Try creating a demo in [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react)

Comment: @iamentafaz I had tried it earlier but since I have a navbar setting the position to ‘fixed’ caused space between my navbar and the sidebar. But your comment made me think about how to use that to make it work, and I’m just gonna set the navbar to fixed and on scroll just make the navbar disappear and push up the sidebar. Thank you!

Comment: @iamentafaz if you want to add your comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell how to fix the problem without any demo but I think you need to use `position` property of `CSS` to your sidebar container to get the desired result.
That's what I could tell for now from the image you've shared.
Let me know if you need more help.